# asp.net Panel get elements with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

i m trying to get all elements of a asp panel with a js.
i tried with

```
function t1()
{

    var v = document.getElementById('<%=pnlFiltri.ClientID %>').elements;
    alert(v.length)
}

 <asp:Panel ID="pnlFiltri" runat="server" DefaultButton="Upload">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" id="tb_Descr" name="Editbox1" value=""/>
 </asp:Panel> 

 <asp:Button ID="Upload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClientClick="t1();return false;" OnClick="b1_Click"/>
```

but not working...

Comment: `document.getElementById(...).elements` will return `undefined`, and thus you will get an error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 function t1()
    {

        var v = document.getElementById('<%=pnlFiltri.ClientID %>');
        var array = v.getElementById("<%=tb_Descr.ClientID %>");
        for (var n = 0; n < array.length; ++n) {
         alert("textbox");
       }
    }

<asp:Panel ID="pnlFiltri" runat="server" DefaultButton="Upload">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" id="tb_Descr" name="Editbox1" value=""/>
 </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to get children count of the panel. Please see the following code

```
function t1() {

        var v = document.getElementById('<%=pnlFiltri.ClientID %>');
        alert(v.children.length)
    }
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlFiltri" runat="server" DefaultButton="Upload">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" ID="tb_Descr" name="Editbox1" value="" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" ID="TextBox1" name="Editbox1" value="" />
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:Button ID="Upload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClientClick="t1();return false;" />
```